# HTA : how to pick up value from each drop down list and search?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am trying to make this HTA working, what it does is to add up all value from each drop down list and search accordingly in a directory that can be selected from another button. I can only make the form of this HTA but dont know how to make the search working.

Also how can I move the directory selection button to the beginning of the line?
so user can pick up directory first then pick what they want to search.

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="2014-03"
   applicationName="2014-03"
   version="1.1"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="static"
    CAPTION="Yes"
    CONTEXTMENU="no"
    ICON="C:\icon\32x32.ico"
    INNERBORDER="no"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    NAVIGATABLE="no"
    SCROLL="no"
    SCROLLFLAT="no"
    SELECTION="no"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal" 
>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

    Sub RunSearch_OnClick()
        msgBox "Success!"
    End Sub 

    Sub TestSub
        For Each objOption in OptionChooser.Options
            If objOption.Selected Then
                Msgbox objOption.InnerText
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

        Sub TestSub1
        For Each objOption in OptionChooser.Options
            If objOption.Selected Then
                Msgbox objOption.InnerText
            End If
        Next
    End Sub


    Sub WindowsLoad

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder (0, "Select The Folder To Enumerate :", (0))
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    Wscript.Quit
    Else
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    objPath = objFolderItem.Path
    End If

    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(objPath)
    For each objFile in objFolder.Files
    If objFolder.Files.Count > 0 Then

    Window.Document.Title = "Information For " & objPath
    strHtml = strHtml & "<td><Font color = Blue>" & objFile.Name & "</font></Br>"
    DataArea.InnerHtml = strHtml
    End If
    Next
    End Sub

</SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>


<select id=extension size="1" name="OptionChooser" onChange="TestSub">
    <option value="0">Selet File Type</option>
    <option value="1">.txt</option>
    <option value="2">.pdf</option>
    <option value="3">.jpg</option>
    <option value="4">.mp3</option>
</select>

<select id=year size="1" name="OptionChooser" onChange="TestSub1">
    <option value="0">Select Year</option>
    <option value="1">2014</option>
    <option value="2">2013</option>
    <option value="3">2012</option>
    <option value="3">2011</option>
    <option value="3">2010</option>
</select>

<select id=month size="1" name="OptionChooser" onChange="TestSub2">
    <option value="0">Select Month</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="1">04</option>
    <option value="2">05</option>
    <option value="3">06</option>
    <option value="1">07</option>
    <option value="2">08</option>
    <option value="3">09</option>
    <option value="1">10</option>
    <option value="2">11</option>
    <option value="3">12</option>

</select>



<input Type = "Button" Value = "Browse For Folder" Name = "Run_Button" onClick = "WindowsLoad"><p></td>
<input type="button" value="Search" name="RunSearch">

</body>

</html>
```

The final HTA should look like this, the search result need to be displayed below the drop down list as text file within a scrollable window and having full path of the files.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In next `HTA` only necessary changes made to display the search result below the drop down list as a  scrollable text area and having full paths of the files.

- On start, a user is prompted to select initial directory (see `WindowsLoad` call within the `Window_Onload` procedure; then *all files* are displayed as no search criteria selected yet.
- Search completed in code for *extension* only to show a possible *how-to* approach (one of few).
- Used a simple *StyleSheet*.
- Some variables defined *script (application) global* to keep their visibility within all procedures.
- Further elementary changes: see the code below.

---

[image: 29548613.HTA look]

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="2014-03"
   applicationName="2014-03"
   version="1.1"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="static"
    CAPTION="Yes"
    CONTEXTMENU="no"
    ICON="C:\icon\32x32.ico"
    INNERBORDER="no"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    NAVIGATABLE="no"
    SCROLL="no"
    SCROLLFLAT="no"
    SELECTION="no"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal" 
>

<!--
'************************
'* StyleSheet
'************************
-->
<style>
BODY
{
   background-color: buttonface;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 8pt;
   margin-top: 2px;
   margin-left: 8px;
   margin-right: 3px;
   margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.button
{
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 8pt;
   width: 40px;
}
textarea
{
   background-color: yellow;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 8pt;
   margin-left: 3px;
   margin-right: 3px;
}
</style>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

'************************
'* Global Variables
'************************
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objPath = ""
    strHtml = ""
    Chooser0 = ""
    Chooser1 = ""
    Chooser2 = ""

'************************
'* Window_Onload
'************************
Sub Window_Onload

    self.Focus()
    self.ResizeTo 800,600

    DataArea.InnerHTML = "<textarea cols=122 rows=25></textarea>"

    WindowsLoad

End Sub


Sub RunSearch_OnClick()
    'msgBox "Success!"
    WindowsLoad
End Sub 

Sub TestSub
  If OptionChooser.Value = "0" Then
    Chooser0 = ""
  Else
    For Each objOption in OptionChooser.Options
        If objOption.Selected Then
          Chooser0 = objOption.InnerText
          Exit For
        End If
    Next
  End If
End Sub

Sub TestSub1
    For Each objOption in OptionChooser1.Options
        If objOption.Selected Then
            Msgbox objOption.InnerText
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub TestSub2
    For Each objOption in OptionChooser2.Options
        If objOption.Selected Then
            Msgbox objOption.InnerText
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub whichFolder
  prevPath = objPath
  Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder _
      (0, "Select The Folder To Enumerate :", (0))
  If objFolder Is Nothing Then
    msgBox "Bye!"
    self.Close()
  Else
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    objPath = objFolderItem.Path
  End If
  If prevPath <> "" then WindowsLoad
End Sub

Sub WindowsLoad
  If objPath = "" Then
    whichFolder
  End If

  Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(objPath)

  Window.Document.Title = "Information For " & objPath & " " & Chooser0
  strHtml = "<textarea cols=122 rows=25>"

  ShowSubFolders objFolder, Chooser0

  DataArea.InnerHtml = strHtml
End Sub

Sub ShowSubFolders(fFolder, strExt)
    'strHtml = strHtml & Chr(10) & fFolder.Path & Chr(10)
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fFolder.Path)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each objFile in colFiles
        If strExt = "" OR UCase(strExt) = _
          "." & UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) Then
            strHtml = strHtml & objFile.Path & Chr(10)
        End If
    Next

    For Each Subfolder in fFolder.SubFolders
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder, strExt
    Next
End Sub

</SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>

<select id=extension size="1" name="OptionChooser" onChange="TestSub">
    <option value="0">Selet File Type</option>
    <option value="1">.txt</option>
    <option value="2">.pdf</option>
    <option value="3">.jpg</option>
    <option value="4">.mp3</option>
</select>

<select id=year size="1" name="OptionChooser1" onChange="TestSub1">
    <option value="0">Select Year</option>
    <option value="1">2014</option>
    <option value="2">2013</option>
    <option value="3">2012</option>
    <option value="3">2011</option>
    <option value="3">2010</option>
</select>

<select id=month size="1" name="OptionChooser2" onChange="TestSub2">
    <option value="0">Select Month</option>
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    <option value="3">03</option>
    <option value="1">04</option>
    <option value="2">05</option>
    <option value="3">06</option>
    <option value="1">07</option>
    <option value="2">08</option>
    <option value="3">09</option>
    <option value="1">10</option>
    <option value="2">11</option>
    <option value="3">12</option>
</select>

<input Type = "button" Value = "Browse For Folder" 
        Name = "Run_Button" onClick = "whichFolder"><p>

<input type="button" value="Search" name="RunSearch"><p>

<div id="DataArea" name="DataArea"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, @JosefZ, There is a bug, can you make it display nothing when I select a folder. also, if there are sub-folders in selected folder, the hta hangs. I would like to search files in directory tree instead of a single folder.

Comment: As you can see in the `ShowSubFolders` procedure, it calls itself recursively to get files in all subdirectory tree (and shown in the picture). What the bug, please? An error message? On my Windows 8.1 it works and does not matter if I run it `D:\VB_scripts\SO\29548613.hta` or `mshta D:\VB_scripts\SO\29548613.hta` or even with fully qualified `mshta` as follows: `C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe ...` or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshta.exe ...`.

Comment: there was no error msg, just when i open a folder that contains subfolders, the hta hangs and shows stop working...@JosefZ

Comment: Debug the `ShowSubFolders` procedure under [Windows Script Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k(v=vs.84).aspx) (WSH) using `WScript.exe` or  `CScript.exe`...

Comment: @JosefZ Could you please have a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756868/remove-button-and-use-dropdown-box-in-hta-vbscript.