# remove button and use dropdown box in hta-vbscript

Tags: vbscript, hta

I am fairly new to **hta & vbscript**. I have a `**hta**` script downloaded from internet to delay reboot of computer.

There are button for delay such as **30 min, 45 min, 60 min** etc.
I would like to use **combobox(Dropdown box)** instead of button.

I also want my vbscript will work with dropdown box.

Below are the code of hta.

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Reboot Notification</title>
    <hta:application id="oMyApp"
        applicationname="Reboot Notification"
        border="dialog"
        BORDERSTYLE="normal"
        caption="yes"
        scroll="no"
        MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
        MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
        showintaskbar="no"
        singleinstance="yes"
        SYSMENU="no"/>
    </head>

    <script language = "VBScript">
        Dim intMinutes
        Dim intSeconds
        Dim strHTAProc
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

        Sub Window_OnLoad
            resizeto 600,450
            moveto 600,400
            intMinutes = 15
            intSeconds = 0
            GetProcessID
            'Run the RebootTimer Sub Procedure Every 1 Second
            iTimerID = window.setInterval("RebootTimer", 1000)
        End Sub

        '*** Get the HTA Application Process ID
        Sub GetProcessID
            strComputer = "."
            Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
            Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select Name, Handle from Win32_Process Where Name = 'mshta.exe'")
            For Each objProcess in colProcesses
                strHTAProc = objProcess.Handle
            Next
        End Sub

        '***** Update the Time to Selected Value *********
        Sub Delay30
            btnDisabled
            intMinutes = 30
            intSeconds = 0
        End Sub

        Sub Delay45
            btnDisabled
            intMinutes = 45
            intSeconds = 0
        End Sub

        Sub Delay60
            btnDisabled
            intMinutes = 60
            intSeconds = 0
        End Sub

          Sub Delay90
            btnDisabled
            intMinutes = 90
            intSeconds = 0
        End Sub

          Sub Delay120
            btnDisabled
            intMinutes = 120
            intSeconds = 0
        End Sub

          Sub Delay240
            btnDisabled
            intMinutes = 240
            intSeconds = 0
        End Sub

Function Document_onKeyDown()

    Dim alt
    alt = window.event.altKey
    Select Case window.event.keyCode
        Case 27,116
            window.event.keyCode = 0
            window.event.cancelBubble = true
            Document_onKeyDown = False
        Case 115
            If alt Then
                window.event.keyCode = 0
                window.event.cancelBubble = true
                Document_onKeyDown = False
            End If
        Case Else
            Document_onKeyDown = True
    End Select

End Function


        '*************************************************

        '*** Disable all of the Buttons Once One is Selected
        Sub btnDisabled
            btnDelay30.Disabled = True
            btnDelay45.Disabled = True
            btnDelay60.Disabled = True
            btnDelay90.Disabled = True
            btnDelay120.Disabled = True
            btnDelay240.Disabled = True
        End Sub

        Sub RebootTimer
            If intSeconds = 0 Then
                If intMinutes = 0 and intSeconds = 0 Then 'Reboot the Workstations
                    objShell.AppActivate strHTAProc
                    objShell.Run "shutdown -r -f -t 0"
                Else
                    intMinutes = intMinutes - 1
                End If
                intSeconds = 59
            Else 
                intSeconds = intSeconds - 1
            End If

            'Update the Clock 
            Clock.innerHTML = "A Reboot Will Occur in " & "<strong>" & intMinutes & ":" & Right("00" & intSeconds, 2) & "</strong>"

            'Activate the HTA Application at 1, 5, and 10 minutes to remind the user
            If intMinutes = 1 and intSeconds = 0 Then
                objShell.AppActivate strHTAProc
            ElseIf intMinutes = 5 and intSeconds = 0 Then
                objShell.AppActivate strHTAProc
            ElseIf intMinutes = 10 and intSeconds = 0 Then
                objShell.AppActivate strHTAProc
            End If

        End Sub

    </script>

    <body onLoad="window.focus()" STYLE="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#9BC59F', EndColorStr='#508855')">
        <h2 p style="text-align: center; "><span>Reboot Notification</h2></span></p>
        <h3 p style="text-align: center; "><span>Your Workstation Requires A Reboot</h3></span></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><span id="Clock"></span></p>      
        <p style="text-align: center;"><input id=btnDelay30 class="button" type="button" value="Delay 30 Minutes" name="btnDelay30" onClick="Delay30"/></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><input id=btnDelay45 class="button" type="button" value="Delay 45 Minutes" name="btnDelay45" onClick="Delay45"/></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><input id=btnDelay60 class="button" type="button" value="Delay 60 Minutes" name="btnDelay60" onClick="Delay60"/></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><input id=btnDelay90 class="button" type="button" value="Delay 90 Minutes" name="btnDelay90" onClick="Delay90"/></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><input id=btnDelay120 class="button" type="button" value="Delay 120 Minutes" name="btnDelay120" onClick="Delay120"/></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><input id=btnDelay240 class="button" type="button" value="Delay 240 Minutes" name="btnDelay240" onClick="Delay240"/></p>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size:14px;"><span>If you have any questions please contact the Helpdesk at ext. ####</span></p>
    </body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

> I can show dropdown box on the hta application but i don't know how to
>   manage vbscript with that.

Comment: "I found this code, fix it for me" is not how this site works. What have you tried to make the code do what you want, and what did not work as you expected?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I can show the dropdown box on hta application but not able to manage vbscript to work with it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The reason why i put above code is i don't want anyone to give extra burdon to troubleshoot.

Comment: If you want us to help make your VBScript code work with your dropdown list you need to show us the VBScript code and the dropdown list that aren't working together. What don't you understand about that?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I will try and put my findings over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should get value from SELECT element. 
Let's say SELECT element has name btnDelay.
To get value of btnDelay you should use btnDelay.Value

Enjoy

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Reboot Notification</title>
    <hta:application id="oMyApp"
        applicationname="Reboot Notification"
        border="dialog"
        BORDERSTYLE="normal"
        caption="yes"
        scroll="no"
        MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
        MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
        showintaskbar="no"
        singleinstance="yes"
        SYSMENU="no"/>
    </head>

    <script language = "VBScript">
        Dim intMinutes
        Dim intSeconds
        Dim strHTAProc
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

        Sub Window_OnLoad
            resizeto 600,550
            moveto 300,300
            intMinutes = 15
            intSeconds = 0
            GetProcessID
            'Run the RebootTimer Sub Procedure Every 1 Second
            iTimerID = window.setInterval("RebootTimer", 1000)
        End Sub

        '*** Get the HTA Application Process ID
        Sub GetProcessID
            strComputer = "."
            Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
            Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select Name, Handle from Win32_Process Where Name = 'mshta.exe'")
            For Each objProcess in colProcesses
                strHTAProc = objProcess.Handle
            Next
        End Sub

        '***** Update the Time to Selected Value *********
    Sub SetDelay
            btnDisabled
            intMinutes = btnDelay.Value
            intSeconds = 0
    End Sub

Function Document_onKeyDown()

    Dim alt
    alt = window.event.altKey
    Select Case window.event.keyCode
        Case 27,116
            window.event.keyCode = 0
            window.event.cancelBubble = true
            Document_onKeyDown = False
        Case 115
            If alt Then
                window.event.keyCode = 0
                window.event.cancelBubble = true
                Document_onKeyDown = False
            End If
        Case Else
            Document_onKeyDown = True
    End Select

End Function


        '*************************************************

        '*** Disable all of the Buttons Once One is Selected
        Sub btnDisabled
            btnDelay.Disabled = True
        End Sub

        Sub RebootTimer
            If intSeconds = 0 Then
                If intMinutes = 0 and intSeconds = 0 Then 'Reboot the Workstations
                    objShell.AppActivate strHTAProc
                    objShell.Run "shutdown -r -f -t 0"
                Else
                    intMinutes = intMinutes - 1
                End If
                intSeconds = 59
            Else 
                intSeconds = intSeconds - 1
            End If

            'Update the Clock 
            Clock.innerHTML = "A Reboot Will Occur in " & "<strong>" & intMinutes & ":" & Right("00" & intSeconds, 2) & "</strong>"

            'Activate the HTA Application at 1, 5, and 10 minutes to remind the user
            If intMinutes = 1 and intSeconds = 0 Then
                objShell.AppActivate strHTAProc
            ElseIf intMinutes = 5 and intSeconds = 0 Then
                objShell.AppActivate strHTAProc
            ElseIf intMinutes = 10 and intSeconds = 0 Then
                objShell.AppActivate strHTAProc
            End If

        End Sub

    </script>

    <body onLoad="window.focus()" STYLE="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#9BC59F', EndColorStr='#508855')">
        <h2 p style="text-align: center; "><span>Reboot Notification</h2></span></p>
        <h3 p style="text-align: center; "><span>Your Workstation Requires A Reboot</h3></span></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><span id="Clock"></span></p>      
    <select size="1" name="btnDelay" onchange="SetDelay">
        <option value="30">Delay 30 Minutes
        <option value="45">Delay 45 Minutes
        <option value="60">Delay 60 Minutes
        <option value="90">Delay 60 Minutes
        <option value="120">Delay 120 Minutes
        <option value="240">Delay 240 Minutes
    </select>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size:14px;"><span>If you have any questions please contact the Helpdesk at ext. ####</span></p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: it works like charm. If possible please suggest some links for vbscript learning.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2764 -- source number one. i used this documentation for many years, while i used ASP as my primary web programming language.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

NOTE: ASP and VBS are from the same family but they are different. Something completely different, some part completely the same.